# Convert list with str elements to list with integer elements

Tags: python-3.x

I am importing data from csv file to python with code below:

```
import csv

excel = open(r"C:\Users\JP Dayao\Desktop\Python\Constraints Study\sample.csv")

raw = csv.reader(excel)

for i in raw:

    print(i)
    
excel.close()
```

The output is below:

```
['21', '34', '25', '31', '27', '36', '24']
```

Desired output is:

```
[21, 34, 25, 31, 27, 36, 24]
```

Please help... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

excel = open(r"C:\Users\JP Dayao\Desktop\Python\Constraints Study\sample.csv")
raw = csv.reader(excel)
raw_int = []

for i in raw:
    for j in i:
        raw_int.append(int(j))

print(raw_int)
excel.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your csv file has a line like `21,34,25,31,27,36,24`. The csv file may contain multiple lines. So you can use list comprehension like this-

```
raw = csv.reader(excel)

print([int(x) for line in raw for x in line])
```

output for a single line csv file:

```
[21, 34, 25, 31, 27, 36, 24]
```

This is a nested list comprehension. The first one `... for line in raw` will loop over all lines in csv file and the second one `for x in line` will loop over every element in that line and convert it to int. If more than one line present in csv line it will be converted into a list

The solution provided by @MohitC doesn't work because in that solution (i.e. `[int(x) for x in raw]`), `x` is itself a list containing elements present in a line and `int()` will not work on list. That is why you need another list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
myList=['21', '34', '25', '31', '27', '36', '24']
newList=[int(i) for i in myList]
[21, 34, 25, 31, 27, 36, 24]
or
newList2=list(map(int,myList))
[21, 34, 25, 31, 27, 36, 24]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.